# How do I fix errors when renaming observations in R for filtering purposes?

Tags: r, rename, mutate

I am trying to rename observations in R so that I can filter and I keep running into errors.  For example, if the data set was

```
       farmer           fruit           number 
1       Sally       strawberries        32
2       Joe         strawberry         12
3       Bob           pear            42
```

but I wanted to calculate how many farmers are growing strawberries.

How would I get it to be

```
       farmer           fruit           number 
1       Sally       **strawberry**          32
2       Joe         strawberry         12
3       Bob           pear            42
```

I tried

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(fruit = str_replace(fruit, "strawberries", "strawberry"))
```

and nothing changed.

I also tried

```
df1 <- df %>% 
+   mutate(fruit = as.character(fruit)) %>%
+   mutate(fruit = replace(fruit, fruit = "strawberries", "strawberry"))
```

and got an error.

Comment: can you add the error message?

Comment: I cant recreate this error in your example data - are you sure the sample data are representative of your real data? If your goal is to filter all fruits that are strawberries or strawberry, you could just use something like `df %>% filter(stringr::str_detect(fruit, "strawb"))`

Answer (score 1):

`(?i)` starts case-insensitive mode

"strawberries" will be replaced by "strawberry" regardless of the case of the characters.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(fruit = str_replace_all(fruit, "(?i)strawberries", "strawberry"))

  farmer      fruit number
1  Sally strawberry     32
2    Joe strawberry     12
3    Bob       pear     42
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(farmer = c("Sally", "Joe", "Bob"), fruit = c("Strawberries", 
"strawberry", "pear"), number = c(32L, 12L, 42L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Comment: What is the (?!)

Comment: Nothing is changing still - im getting back the exact same data frame

Comment: have you loaded the packages dplyer and stringr?

Answer (score 0):

Here a small data set that TarJae provided would make things easier for anyone who wants to help.

In fact you are right from the begining, but I suspect that you confused `df`  and `df1`

```
df <- structure(list(farmer = c("Sally", "Joe", "Bob"), fruit = 
c("strawberries", "strawberry", "pear"), number = c(32L, 12L, 42L)),
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))


##  df
##   farmer        fruit number
## 1  Sally strawberries     32
## 2    Joe   strawberry     12
## 3    Bob         pear     42
```

If I apply your very own command but don't assign it to `df1` I have what you expect.

```
df %>%   mutate(fruit = str_replace(fruit, "strawberries", "strawberry"))
```

of course there is nothing wrong to assigning it to df1

```
df1 <-  df %>%   mutate(fruit = str_replace(fruit, "strawberries", "strawberry"))
```

but then we need to check `df1`

```
  ## df1
  ##       farmer      fruit number
  ##     1  Sally strawberry     32
  ##     2    Joe strawberry     12
  ##     3    Bob       pear     42
```

This is because the `mutate`function makes a copy of the table `df`, so the table df is left unchanged. Indeed, in my opinion `mutate` here is a poor choice of name